# Ember, how to inherit from a custom Adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a global custom *Adapter*:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'http://reportsdashboard-v2.daliaresearch.com.dev'
});
```

And another specific for one *Model*:

```
// app/adapters/chart.js
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'http://reportsdashboard-v2.daliaresearch.com.dev',
  buildURL: function(type, id, snapshot) {
    return this.host + '/' + this.namespace + '/reports/' + snapshot.record.get('report.id') + '/charts/' + id;
  }
});
```

As you can see there is a duplication defining the attributes *'namespace'* and *'api'*. This is one of the reasons I'm trying to inherit the *ApplicationAdapter* from the *ChartsAdapter*.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer: I'm a newby in Ember so take this explanation with critical mind set*

Naming the *CustomAdapter* class:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

const ApplicationAdapter = ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'http://reportsdashboard-v2.daliaresearch.com.dev'
});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

Importing it from the *ChartAdapter*:

```
// app/adapters/chart.js
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(type, id, snapshot) {
    return this.host + '/' + this.namespace + '/reports/' + snapshot.record.get('report.id') + '/charts/' + id;
  }
});
```